# converting geometry of SRID 0 to geography

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type

My geometry columns have SRID of 0. Can I simply convert them to geography as such:

routes.geom::geography <-> pc.geom::geography as distance

in order to get "distance" in metres?

P.S - "routes.geom" is a linestring column, and "pc.geom" is a point column.

here is a snippet of how it is used, (extracted from my main query):

```
    FROM point_center as pc
    
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT routes.id_num, routes.geom::geography <-> pc.geom::geography AS dist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GEOGRAPHY` type instantiation assumes `EPSG:4326` by default, so you *can* simply cast your `GEOMETRY` types, and even get correct results if they actually *are* referenced in `EPSG:4326`.

---

However, it is **highly advisable** to add the correct SRID to the `GEOMETRY` column and values:

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(<TYPE>, <SRID>)
    USING ST_SetSRID(geom, <SRID>)
;

-- VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;
```

**Note:**

A `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY` will render the respective statement **unable to utilize a spatial index on the `GEOMETRY` column**; in order to benefit from an index lookup where possible, add a functional index on the actual `CAST`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON <table> USING GIST ( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) );

-- VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;
;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139327/discussion-on-answer-by-geozelot-converting-geometry-of-srid-0-to-geography).